# Calculating 2 rightmost decimal digits of large number (modular exponentiation)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm asked to calculate 2 rightmost decimal digits of  large number, e.g. 3^2005. The hint is to use some modular trick (probably Euler phi function). Can anyone show me how to reduce the exponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Euler $\,\phi(100) = 40,\,$ so $\rm\,{\rm mod}\ 100\!:\ \color{#c00}{3^{\large 40}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,3^{\large 40J+\color{#0a0}K}\equiv (\color{#c00}{3^{\large 40}})^J 3^{\large K}\equiv \color{#c00}1^{\large J}3^{\large K}\equiv 3^{\large\color{#0a0}K}$

In your case $\ 2005\ =\ 40\cdot 50 + \color{#0a0}5,\ $ so applying the above yields$\ \ldots$

Comment: Actually $\phi(100)=40$, but the calculation remains almost identical.

Comment: @David Thanks. I was using Carmichael $\lambda$ vs. Euler $\phi$. Changed to $\phi$ for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a really *really* easy question: what are the two rightmost digits of $1234567$?

Obviously, $67$.  Next question: what does this have to do with modular arithmetic?  Answer: it's really just another way of saying that
$$1234567\equiv67\pmod{100}\ .$$
So, you need to simplify $3^{2005}$ modulo $100$.  BTW, this question is "obviously" about 9 years old ;-)

Using Euler's function as you suggest is a good start - can you find an exponent $m$ such that $3^m$ is *very* simple modulo $100$?  Then can you find a higher value of $m$ with the same property?  And another?  And one which is very close to $2005$?

Comment: thank you, I didn't realize 2 right most digits is suggesting mod 100...

Answer (score 0):

I pulled out the calculator on Windows and multiplied $3$ by itself repeatedly until I got $01$ for the rightmost two digits: $3^{20} = 3,486,784,401.$

So $3^0 \equiv 3^{20} \equiv 3^{40} \equiv ... \equiv 3^{2000} \equiv 1$ (mod 100).

Likewise $3^{2005} \equiv 3^{5} \equiv 43$ (mod 100).